# Permanently refreshing fabric.js canvas

Tags: fabricjs

I am working on the development of a software artifact that uses fabric.js-1.6.6. The code will be used by other programmers who might be adding/removing objects to/from the canvas and interacting with them.

In order to avoid delays caused by other programmers' refreshing routines, I decided to implement a global refreshing function that is transparent to users of my code. The refreshing routine looks like this:

```
    (function render() {
        fabric.util.requestAnimFrame(render);
        canvas.renderAll();
    })();
```

I know it might be not super efficient (as the canvas gets refreshed all the time), but I am preventing other programmers from having to deal with rendering the canvas on their own when implementing specialized objects whose appearance changes permanently and, thus, require the canvas to update.

Recently, I tried to migrate my code to fabric 2.0.0 beta 4 but the canvas is not updated anymore. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Also, is there any better, more efficient way to have a permanent canvas refreshing routine? What I decided to do was inspired on the [Animating polygon points](http://fabricjs.com/polygon-animation) official fabric demo, but my canvas requires a significantly higher number of objects that are changing all the time, so this might not be the best strategy.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle where using that function makes the canvas not render in fabric 2.0.0beta4?

Answer (score 0):

My personal suggestion is to start watching at 2.0.0
The new version implement a new method called `requestRenderAll` that will make use of requestAnimationFrame properly.

Consider that having the canvas autorefreshing every 16ms may be an overkill.
To me the most elegant solution is to ask other developers to use requestRenderAll and not renderAll.

chained calling of `requestRenderAll` will have no effect, since till the animation is still in request stage, other do not get requested.